# add link title, if title is empty on <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have dynamically added list of links and title is added to the link but some of the link are add empty titles so i need to add a default title using JavaScript

```
<a class="tip visible-phone" data-original-title=" " href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="">view</a>
```

Comment: Is it the title, or data-original-title that you want to check?

Comment: It is not clear what do you expect, specially with this data attribute original-title. What will be the default title? Same for all links?

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you need...

```
$("a[data-original-title=' ']").data("original-title", "default title");
```

or...

```
$("a[title='']").attr("title", "default title");
```

depending on whether it's the title attribute, or data-original-title.

Just add that line of code after you have dynamically created the links.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.tip.visible-phone[title='']").attr("title", "default title");
```

Comment: i don't know why this has been downvoted, downvoter, could you elaborate on this?

Comment: SO, really have to do something about this anonymous downvotes. Its really irritating.

Comment: It would be great if on first downvote a comment has to be posted IMO

Comment: ya, exactly I was thinking about something like that. If they don't comment then down vote becomes invalid(or even becomes upvote ;-))